# Тянущийся UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

Привет. Подскажите, как можно растянуть UIView (показал, как должно быть на картинке)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где растянуть? В интерфейс билдере или в рантайме?

Comment: В самом приложении. Нужно как то автоматически расчитывать высоту View от последней ячейки до нижней части экрана

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то `UIView` надо привязать (autolayout констрейнтами) слева/права/низу к супервьюхе. Сверху - привязать к `UITableView`. Так же таблице нужно выставить констрейнт высоты и связать его с аутлетом. В коде нужно после перезагрузки таблицы выставлять высоту (через этот аутлет) в **высота ячейки * кол-во ячеек**. Хотя я не уверен, что это лучшее решение, но зато довольно простое в плане реализации.